# WordPress: Wrap li content with a span

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I've added styles to a `ul` tag so that the bullet points will be a different color. The problem with this is that it also changes to color of the `li` content whereas I only intend it to change the bullet point color.

I've tried using `pseudo` styling but it did not work out well.

Since I am using WordPress the `li` will be within the content editor and therefore would be ideal if all content within the `li` tags are wrapped in a `span` so that I can filter out the styling of the `li` from the content within it.

I know this could be possible with `preg_replace` but I'm still new to PhP in general.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  // Wordpress Add <span> Here
    Content Goes Here
  // Wordpress Add </span> Here
 </li>
</ul>
```

Ultimately is it possible to automatically wrap content within a `li` with the use of a back-end function and filter rather than having the user manually add it within the WordPress content editor?

I hope this has made sense to you, I tried my best.

**CSS as requested**

```
ul {
 color: #2e6c9e;
 padding-left: 22px;
}

ul li {
 color: #636466; // This does not work :(
}
```

**NOTE:**

I need an alternative to `:before` and `:after`

For those who are not clear, I'm adding the `ul` element through WordPress content editor. Since this will need to be user friendly I need a method to slip in a `span` before the li content so that users with no technical knowledge can insert `ul`'s without the color conflict.

Comment: Where is your CSS code that styles ul list items?

Comment: @K.I I've added my CSS to the post for reference

Comment: Jan Mellström's answer is correct.

Comment: You cannot change the bullet point color, as it's neither part of the `ul`, `li` or even `li:before`

Comment: @K.I Yes I know but I've said that this method did not work for me since when the li breaks on to two lines the text goes underneath the li. I need an alternative method.

Comment: Did you try wrapping your li's in spans and style them?

Comment: @K.I Yes but adding a color to the `span` also changes to color of the bullet point.

Comment: Wordpress has pretty many settings you can use so I suggest you look at their wiki, maybe this link can help a little: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can color the bullet in a `<li>`. So you have to make your own bullet and you can easily do that with CSS.

Here is one sample that I usually use:

```
li {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}
li:before {
    position: absolute;
        top: -3px;
        left: -18px;
    content: "• ";
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #222;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this but I tried using pseudo styling but it did not work out well when the li content went on to multiple lines. A good alternative though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <span>
        test
     </span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

With this CSS:

```
ul  {
        color: red;
        padding-left: 22px;
    }
ul span
    {
        color: green; 
    }
```

It works for me. If it doesn't work then there might be other CSS thats being applied to your code in which case add !important to your styles. Styling classes rather than elements would also improve your code.

Comment: This is what Im trying to achieve but without manual input. The content is being added through WordPress and users without technical knowledge won't be able to do this. I need some kind of method in the back-end that will automatically slide in the span tags

Comment: Now I understand your question 100% :) Im almost sure what you are looking for can be done, however I dont know how. I would need to research that myself.

Comment: Im sure I've seen this done elsewhere but I just can't remember. Thanks for your help by the way :)